# IGO_PROFILES not being populated by setUserInfo

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, einstein, einstein-recommendations, email-tracking

I'm trying to generate email recommendations with Einstein, but I can't get users added to the IGO_PROFILES data extension.

I'm following the directions to the letter as far as I can tell.
I'm also tracking page views. PI_CONTENTVIEWS is populating with lots of views.

In the Reporting section of Einstien, I can even search contacts by the email I'm testing with, and I can see my page views being associated with my 'profile.' But the profile itself hasn't made it into IGO_PROFILES so I can't write queries that join on IGO_PROFILES and PI_CONTENTVIEWS, which is ultimately what I'm trying to do.

Here's the code from my site.

```javascript
var mcid = urlParams.get('mcid');
etmc.push(["setOrgId", MY_MID]);
etmc.push(["trackPageView", {
  "item": "/efficacy-and-safety"
}]);
etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {
  "email": mcid
}]);
```

Comment: Maybe this is not proper syntax, because it is missing the " " around mcid. If this is not directly done by urlParams.get('mcid'); just check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the call to `setUserInfo` must come before the one to `trackPageView`, or key parameters will be missing from the network request.

Answer (score 1):

All the `setXxxx` methods only update variables locally, in the user's browser's context. They do not trigger communication with the server and hence cause no tracking by itself.

Make sure to always follow `setXxxx` methods with one of the `trackXxxx` methods to actually update the database on the server. `trackPageView` (with or without further parameters) is one option. More in the [docs](https://joernberkefeld.github.io/SFMC-Cookbook/einstein/recommendation/#tracking-and-other-collect-code-features)